# Underscore JS template If loop issue

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, tooltip

I am trying to add an attribute (`rel="tooltip"`) based on if condition

```
<div class="symbol"><span title="<%= data%>" <% if ( data.length > 9 ) { rel="tooltip" }%>></span></div>
```

If I am adding an alert inside if loop it works, where as the attribute change does not work.

Comment: corrected it. I was trying to call a function in the model

Comment: Don't you mean something like: `rel="<%= data.length > 9 ? "tooltip" : "" %>"`?  What does this have to do with underscore.js?

Comment: Thanks rocket it worked... add it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with JavaScript (or Underscore.js) at all.

`<% %>` are ASP tags, and `rel="tooltip"` is just setting a variable.  You need to have ASP echo out `"tooltip"` (like you did with the title).

```
<div class="symbol"><span title="<%= data %>" rel="<%= data.length > 9 ? "tooltip" : "" %>></span></div>
```